# do these tables fit the database First Normal Form?

Tags: database, database-design

table users

```
userId    name     company    company_address     url

1         Joe       ABC       Work Lane         abc.com

2         Jake      ABC        Work Lane        xyz.com

3         tom       XYZ       Job Street        abcde.com

4         jim      XYZ       Job Street         fexyz.com
```

the second table

```
id          name          favourite_food_1          favourite_food_2   

1           Sam              Curry                  Steak       

 2           Lucy           Chicken                      Burgers
```

if the table don't fit for the 1NF,why? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first table fits 1NF. The second does not - there's a repeating group with the two favorite food fields. Not everyone necessarily has two favorite foods (or any favorite foods at all, or has 3+ favorite foods), so those fields are nullable, and therefore causes the table to fail 1NF.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't 1NF only mean each value has to be atomic?  In other words, every relational database table is in 1NF, since sets of values aren't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

1NF sets the very basic rules for an organized database:

**1: Eliminate duplicative columns from the same table.
2: Create separate tables for each group of related data and identify each row with a unique column (the primary key).**

The problem with your Database tables is "Name"(duplicate column).

Answer (score 1):

Every relational table always satisfies 1NF. A SQL table is in 1NF if it accurately represents a relation, i.e. it has unique column names and doesn't permit nulls or duplicate rows.

Comment: Doesn't a comma separated list of values of say, phone numbers violate 1NF?